# I can't make Wear OS Project with Android stduio

Tags: android-studio, wear-os

When I make Wear OS app with default name(MyApplication), It works well..

But When I make Wear OS app with custom name(ex. WearOsTestProject)...

[Create New Project Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfaM1.png)

[Project name changed to MyApplication...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90tl5.png)

it fixed MyApplication ... I can't build it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was Android studio problem..

I solved this problem by  re-install android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is Android Studio's problem. I use IntelliJ instead